# Need to know all the listeners in a NSNotification object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotificationCenter object.  I need to know all the listeners and the events they listen to.  Is there anything that I can do to get this listing?

Comment: Without more information on what you're trying to achieve, it will be very difficult to help you. Notifications through NSNotificationCenter are not _meant_ to be managed by the user - the entire purpose is to loosely couple events and subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope;   why do you need to know?

The whole goal of notifications is to create a loosely couple system of observers vs. notifiers.   The very question of "knowing all" doesn't make sense as it is perfectly possible that there will be observers of the notification that come from code you didn't author at all (assuming a system notification).

And, of course, if it is a notification that you create that is named uniquely to your app, then you should also know all possible observers.

Comment: i am not getting my events notified and hence i wanted to debug it.  That was the reason i needed to know what the listeners and observers were.

Comment: For debugging? Makes sense.  But -- still -- nope, no way to do that.

Comment: Fixed the issue today.  Was using the wrong object as a sender at one place and it screwed the rest of the places up! Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is debug which listeners are listening for which notifications, you can log this information pretty easily:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter].debugDescription);
```

or

```
po [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

will print out something like this in the debugger:

```
<NSNotificationCenter:0x6080000c0070>
Name, Object, Observer, Options
NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification, 0x7fff882e5958, 0x604000100cf0, 1400
NSAntialiasThresholdChangedNotification, 0x7fff882e5958, 0x100e00000, 1400
NSAntialiasThresholdChangedNotification, 0x7fff882e5958, 0x6040001e0300, 1400
NSAntialiasThresholdChangedNotification, 0x7fff882e5958, 0x100f1aa10, 1400
kCFLocaleCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification, 0x7fff882e5958, 0x7fff882e5a38, 1001
...
```